Centering vertically multiple-line list element to the 'dot'
I have a list that at some screen-size breaks into multiple lines
The issue is that in this case I want my list bullet to align vertically in the middle of the text shown.
So practically if I have 3 lines inside the same list element, I want the bullet/market to show up next to the second line instead of the first, and if I have 2 lines, the dot should line itself between the two lines.
I tried vertical-align so far, no success and couldn't find an appropriate idea for my question yet.

The standard bullet does not allow for adjustment in this manner.
It is necessary to create a pseudo-element for the marker and then align it using. say, flexbox.


li {
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

li:before {
  content: "\2022";
  margin-right: 1em;
}

.wider {
  width: 450px;
}
<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis perferendis tempore nesciunt, cum molestias ut necessitatibus nostrum incidunt adipisci odio.</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li class="wider">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis perferendis tempore nesciunt, cum molestias ut necessitatibus nostrum incidunt adipisci odio.</li>
</ul>




Thank you! I figured it out how to incorporate this (relevant pieces) into my actual work, and it's working!

Here is an idea using border-image to replace the default marker


ul {
  font-size: 20px;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  /* .2em = radius
      20px = control the position
  */
  border-image: 
   radial-gradient(circle closest-side at .2em 50%,#000 80%,#0000) 
   fill 0//20px
}
<ul>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin quis neque felis. Pellentesque commodo velit diam, a egestas nisi molestie sed. Phasellus luctus lobortis orci nec venenatis.</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur </li>
</ul>




I have an ul list here in this snippet and I have used a ::before pseudo-class on the li element and as you can see the dots are vertically aligned with the text. I hope this is what you wanted to achieve.


ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

li::before {
  content: "•";
  margin-right: 10px;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>List Alignment Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
    <li>Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
    <li>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris.</li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>



